# Display alert with email id

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a table with first name, last name and email address coming from a JSON:

```
<TableBody>
  {PostData.map((list, index) => (
    <TableRow key={index}>
      <TableCell>{list.first_name}</TableCell>
      <TableCell>{list.last_name}</TableCell>
      <TableCell>{list.last_name}</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  ))}
</TableBody>
```

However, I would like to have an alert with the email when clicking a button.

```
<TableBody>
  {PostData.map((list, index) => (
    <TableRow key={index}>
      <TableCell>{list.first_name}</TableCell>
      <TableCell>{list.last_name}</TableCell>
      <TableCell><Button onClick={()=>{ alert({list.email}); }}> Show email </Button></TableCell>
   </TableRow>
  ))}
</TableBody>
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you have braces around `list.email` when you don't need them. should just be `alert(list.email)`

Comment: Your last `TableCell` is not closed in the second snippet and in the first one the last cell uses `last_name`. All those aside, what's the error you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TableCell><Button onClick={()=>{ alert(list.email); }}> Show email </Button>
```

### list.email not Wrapper by braces {} !!